# reading in text file data to create polygons java

Tags: java, parsing, text-files, delimiter, polygons

Ive read in text file data before using delimiters and parsing but I cant seem to figure out how to tackle this file. The first line is the number of polygon shapes, then the each x/y (separated by commas) points are separated by :'s and then a | separates the rgb color value. I havent worked with anything before where data isnt separated by a new line and this is really confusing me. I basically need a loop that will get an int array of x values, y values and then three separate ints for each R, G, and B. Before the loop iterates again ill send the data into a constructor for a new polygon.

> 5
>   382,100:352,135:332,172:327,214:340,277:372,316:421,334:493,346:539,325:567,301:589,254:602,202:593,154:555,126:507,99:442,91|102,102,0
>   409,152:402,170:411,185:431,185:434,167:425,153|51,51,255
>   502,180:517,183:527,171:525,158:506,152:496,163|0,51,255
>   381,223:389,247:408,271:440,292:481,296:511,286:538,251:537,230:518,247:502,265:467,273:437,266:410,250|255,0,102
>   366,375:355,329:338,267:328,208:333,175:352,137:382,104:436,92:505,100:593,156:602,204:590,249:572,295:559,356:606,369:628,333:607,345:581,328:593,295:607,247:613,203:597,142:554,111:486,83:428,81:384,87:352,108:329,140:318,175:315,213:316,243:324,288:339,332:347,353:320,343:339,367|0,0,0

I havent gotten too far and would appreciate any advice.

```
int numShapes, counter=0;
        try
        {
            File myfile = new File (fileToOpen);
            Scanner textScan = new Scanner(myfile); // reads in date from text file
            numShapes = Integer.parseInt(textScan.nextLine()); //read in first line (number of shapes) and parse to int
            while (textScan.hasNextLine()) //
            {
                //read in all the points until you hit the | that starts color info
                textScan.useDelimiter("|");
                while(textScan.hasNext())
                {

                }
                //add points to shape
                // in loop - shapeList.get(counter).addPoint();


            }   // end of loop to read in shape text file contents
            textScan.close(); //closes shape file

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(theFrame, "I/O Problem - File not Saved");
        }
```

Here is the constructor I will use for the polygon.

```
MyPoly(int [] xpts, int [] ypts, int npts, Color col)
```

Comment: How large do you expect your file to be?

Comment: And, finally, do you or don't you have newlines after the RGB values?

Comment: The text file example is about the largest it will be. There isnt necessarily a newline after rgb value, depends arbitrarily on how many points are in each polygon listed.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot be guaranteed that there will always be newlines, then your only feasible option is to load the entire file into a string and then use a StringTokenizer to parse it piece by piece.

However, I have a hard time believing that there are no newlines, considering the fact that in the sample text there appear to be newlines.  So, if by any chance newlines can be guaranteed, then you have another, much easier option:

Load the file line by line, and use `String.split()` to split each line down to its constituent parts.  So, for example, you would first split the line on `|` to separate points from the RGB, then you would split the points on `,` to separate each individual point, then you would split each individual point on `:` to obtain coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Read each line like that (number of lines is useless)

```
while ((a_line=textScan.nextLine())!=null)
     {
```

And treat each line like that:

split POINTS | COLOR

split POINT 1: POINT 2: ...

and split POINT and COLOR by ,

```
// example with a line
String a_line="366,375:355,329:338,267:328,208:333,175:352,137:382,104:436,92:505,100:593,156:602,204:590,249:572,295:559,356:606,369:628,333:607,345:581,328:593,295:607,247:613,203:597,142:554,111:486,83:428,81:384,87:352,108:329,140:318,175:315,213:316,243:324,288:339,332:347,353:320,343:339,367|0,0,0";

// SPLIT POINTS | COLOR
String parts[]=a_line.split("\\|");

// Should be 2
System.out.println("PARTS:"+parts.length);

if (parts.length!=2) {} // STOP ?

System.out.println("PART LEFT:"+parts[0]);

System.out.println("PART RIGHT:"+parts[1]);

// SPLIT POINTS
String points[]=parts[0].split("\\:");

int numpoints=points.length;
System.out.println("POINTS:"+numpoints);

for (int k=0;k<numpoints;k++)
{
    // ONE POINT
    String one_point[]=points[k].split("\\,");
    //Should be 2
    if (one_point.length!=2) {continue;} // STOP ?

    int point_X=Integer.parseInt(one_point[0]);
    int point_Y=Integer.parseInt(one_point[1]);
    System.out.println("X="+point_X+" Y="+point_Y);

    // YOU MUST STORE THAT !
}

// SPLIT COLOR
String colors[]=parts[1].split("\\,");
//Should be 3
System.out.println("COLORS:"+colors.length);
if (colors.length!=3) {} // STOP ?

int color_R=Integer.parseInt(colors[0]);
int color_G=Integer.parseInt(colors[1]);
int color_B=Integer.parseInt(colors[2]);
System.out.println("R="+color_R+" G="+color_G+" B="+color_B);
```